# How to set this kind of constraints: UIImageView's width based on UILabel's Length in AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I already set UIImageView.width（Green Color Background） == UILabel.width + 20 in my tableView cell ，but when the label's content changing , the label 's height is changing at first ,but I want the label to grow wider first , if it can't be more wider then grow higher. what 's the problem here

[image]

Comment: preferedcontentwidth is the new property introduced in iOS8.its in xib or storyboard file.set the preferedcontentwidth to auto and run the app

Comment: in ios7 ，can I do this?

Comment: check ur xib first.. if preferedcontentwidth property is there then select auto

Answer (score 0):

**Hi yes you can do it. I am explaining below how can u do it with auto layout.**

> At the time of applying constraint, instead of giving hight and width
>   to `UIImageView` just try to give it three constraint with `UILabel` which
>   are " Equal Width, Equal Height and Aspect Ratio"
>
> For Applying these three constraints with `UILabel` the shortcut is just
>   drag and drop your mouse cursor from `UIImage` to `UIlabel` with right
>   click only, so you can see above three options. After applying it ,give
>   `UIlabel` Leading and trailing constraint( or whatever u want) and most important thing, set
>   your `UIlabel` to size to content fit. For `UILabel`,shortcut is just
>   click on `UILabel` and click on top toolbar's tab EDITOR and you will
>   find option for setting `UILABEL` as size to content fit so after
>   setting it UILabel will automatically set its frame as per its content
>   and so as `UIImageView`.

Comment: because i am using it in the tableview cell , how can i do the size to content fit in code ? because now I find cells layout good if the cell is created , but the cell layout wrong when it's a reused cell-_-

Comment: Like that :- UILabel *lb;
    lb.text = @"AG";
    [lb sizeToFit];